# get top of a div

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="xyz.com/#contact">click here</a>
```

After Click its redirect to xyz.com/#contact,

Now I want to get the top position of div #abc

```
//set the value as a variable, and remove the #
var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
```

Got hash_value = contact

```
// adding #
hash_value = '#'+hash_value;
```

Got hash_value = #contact

```
var top=$(hash_value).offsetTop;
alert (top);
```

now the alert box says [object Window]

```
var top=$('').offsetTop;
alert (top);
```

now also the alert box says [object Window]

even  offset().top; also saying the same value.
how to get top of the div?

thanks in advance

Comment: i think there typo error `var top=$(hash_value).offseTop;` to be `offsetTop`

Comment: did you mean to use the $.offset() function? `var top=$(hash_value).offset().top;`

Comment: @Imperative Same result

Comment: little offtop: why did the first you take away `#` and then again add?

Comment: are you sure that div with `id = "abc"` on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj57M/), using the code i used in the comment section.

```
$(function() {
    alert( $('#foo').offset().top );
});
```

Guessing from your error i think your jquery selector must be faulty somehow.

Also the `.offsetTop` property is only available on native Javascript objects.
If you want to use it on a jquery object, you must select the JS object first:
`alert( $('#some-id').get(0).offsetTop );`
The jquery function `offset()` simplifies that access.